# why does try catch hide variable from rest of code

Tags: vb.net

Why does try catch hide variable from rest of code in vb.net.

I've searched the net and found some C# answers but I don't understand C# well enough to understand what they are talking about.

```
     Public Function GetUsers(ByVal Path As String) As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of System.IO.DirectoryInfo)
    Dim users As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of System.IO.DirectoryInfo)
    Dim DDLEXEPath As String = Path
    'this is start directory
    Dim curPath = DDLEXEPath.Substring(0, DDLEXEPath.LastIndexOf("\"))

    Try
        Dim diTop As New DirectoryInfo(curPath)
        users = diTop.EnumerateDirectories
    Catch UnAuthTop As UnauthorizedAccessException
        Debug.WriteLine("{0}", UnAuthTop.Message)
    Catch LongPath As Exception
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", LongPath.Message)
    End Try
    Return users
End Function
```

I get an error that user in "Return user" is uninitialized. I've assigned it a value in the try block.

I've played with simple strings following the same format and get the same error.

It's been a long month so far;-(

Thanks.

Comment: try catch hide variable ? your concept may be wrong it is a initialization problem ..try new key word

Answer (score 4):

"Try/catch" doesn't "hide" anything.  But since you assign "users" inside the "try", and since (by definition) there's no guarantee the "try" will complete, VB.Net considers "users" "uninitialized" at the return.

SOLUTION:

Explicitly initialize users *outside* of the try/catch:

```
    users = Nothing
    Try
        Dim diTop As New DirectoryInfo(curPath)
        users = diTop.EnumerateDirectories
    Catch UnAuthTop As UnauthorizedAccessException
        Debug.WriteLine("{0}", UnAuthTop.Message)
    Catch LongPath As Exception
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", LongPath.Message)
    End Try
    Return users
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I am impressed with the users here. I'm bad. That's all it was. It needed to be initialized to nothing.  (I'm supposed to be able to mark this post answered, correct? Where/how do I do this?)

Answer (score 0):

Because try opens a new scope and your return statement is outside this scope.

Solution 1: Move the return inside the try block and put it there as the last line.

Solution 2: Move the dim to before the try and keep only the assignment within the try.

Answer (score 0):

you only set the value of users in the try catch blocks.

The following only defines the user type

```
 Dim users As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of System.IO.DirectoryInfo)
```

add new to initialize it

```
 Dim users As new System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of System.IO.DirectoryInfo)
```

Answer (score 0):

What the error message is telling you is that `users` must be assigned a value before you can `Return` it (or do anything else *but* assign it, for that matter). So, just explicitly state that `users` is to be set to `Nothing` when you declare it.

```
Dim users As IEnumerable(Of DirectoryInfo) = Nothing
```